# Motivation of Virasoro algebra

Tags: virasoro-algebra, lie-algebras

I have a question on definition/motivation of Virasoro algebra. Recall that Virasoro algebra is an infinite Lie algebra generated by elements $L_n$ $(n\in \mathbb{Z})$ and $c$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with relations
$$
[L_m,L_n]=(m-n)L_{m+n}+\frac{c}{12}(m^3-m)\delta_{m+n,0}.
$$
A typical explanation of this definition is the following.

> Define vector fields $l_n=-z^n\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. They form a Lie algebra of infinitesimal conformal transformation 
>   $$
> [l_m,l_n]=(m-n)l_{m+n}.
> $$ 
>   So the Virasoro algebra is a central extension of this algebra by $c$. $c$ is called the central charge.

My questions are

1. How can one see that the Lie algebra above is associate to infinitesimal conformal transformation?
2. What is the central charge $c$ intuitively? Why are we interested in such a central extension?

As to second question, I don't have enough physics background to check what the central charge $c$ means in physics literature.

At this point, I don't have any intuition and have trouble in digesting the concept. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try  Ch. 9: Conformal Invariance Sec. 9.1: Energy momentum tensor-Virasoro algebra of the book Statistical Field Theory Vol. 2 by Itzykson and Drouffe. Maybe you could work around pg. 514 on  translations, complex dilatations, and special conformal transformations related to $d/dz, zd/dz,$ and $z^2d/dz$.The central charge is discussed in the next sub-section from a physical and mathematical perspective. 

Comment: As a first step at understanding the relations, I always recall that $exp(-c \cdot z^2d/dz)f(z)=exp[c \cdot d/d(1/z)]f(1/(1/z))=f(1/(c+1/z))=f(z/(cz+1)),$ a special conformal transformation. Note $zd/dz=d/d(ln(z))$ for the dilatation.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you try to mean in the second comment. I would appreciate it if you could post a bit more detail as an answer.

Answer (score 21):

1 is standard (it's the correspondence between analytic complex functions and conformal maps). For 2, in physics, one really deals with projective representations, not just ordinary representations (this is because a quantum state is really a ray in Hilbert space rather than a vector). A projective representation of an algebra without central charge is the same as an ordinary representation of the algebra with a (potentially) non-zero central charge. It's easier to work with ordinary representations, so people use the centrally extended algebra.

Comment: Thanks you for letting us know the projective representation point of view. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

I will answer (2) quickly: You can refer to my response to this other question: [Why does bosonic string theory require 26 spacetime dimensions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99643/why-does-bosonic-string-theory-require-26-spacetime-dimensions/99650#99650)

In String Theory (physics) there are "quantum operators", and the relation they satisfy are precisely this Virasoro relation. And not just that, but $c=D$, the **space-time dimension**! So it is at least extremely important in unifying the theories of physics via strings, because this relation helps us determine the dimension of our universe. You can view this term proportional to the central charge as a "quantum effect" (i.e. it only appears when you take your classical system and quantize it).

Why $c=D$?: The propagation ("worldsheet") of a 1-dimensional string (fundamental physical object in the theory) in space-time (dimension $D$) is described by functions $X^\mu$, where the index $\mu$ ranges from 0 to $D−2$. They decompose into modes $a^\mu_n$ (for satisfying the string wave-equation). These modes end up mixing and defining quantum operators $L_m$, and the commutator-relations amongst these modes spews out the Virasoro relation with $c=D$.

As for some rigorous intuition which will help with question (1): $c$ can be regarded as multiplying the unit operator, and when adjoined to the Lie algebra generated by the $L_m$ it lies in the center of that extended algebra. (I picked this up when working through Becker-Becker-Schwarz String theory textbook).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Chris. May I ask why multiplication by the unit vector is related to the space dimension?

Answer (score 3):

**How to see that $-z^{m+1}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}$ is related to an infinitesimal conformal transformation:**

With $\omega=\frac{z^{-m}}{m}$ and $z=(m \cdot \omega)^{\frac{-1}{m}}$,  the exponential mapping gives

$exp[-t\cdot z^{m+1}\frac{\partial }{\partial z}]f(z)=exp[t\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial \omega}]f[(m \cdot \omega)^{\frac{-1}{m}}]=f[(m \cdot (\omega+t))^{\frac{-1}{m}}]=f\left [\frac{z}{(1+\ m \cdot t \cdot z^m)^{\frac{1}{m}}}  \right ]=f(g_{m}(z,t)).$

Consistently, $g_{m}(g_{m}(z,s),t)=g_{m}(z,s+t).$

So the exponential mapping induced by the tangent vector results in composition of $f$ with $g_{m}(z,t)=z-\ t\cdot z^{m+1} +\ ....$.

Then to first order in $t$, a Taylor series expansion in $t$ about $t=0$ of the infinitesimal composition gives

$f(z-\ t\cdot z^{m+1})\approx f(z)-{f}'(z)z^{m+1}\cdot t=(1-\ t \cdot z^{m+1}\frac{\partial }{\partial z})f(z),$

and in the domain of analyticity of $g_{m}(z,t)$, the mappings are conformal.

*Some interesting associated combinatorics:*

1) $g_m$ is related to the e.g.f. for planar m-ary trees and double factorials (m=1), triple factorials (m=2), quartic (m=3), etc. (Cf. [OEIS A094638](https://oeis.org/A094638))

2) The compositional inverse of $h(x)= x-\ t\cdot x^{m+1}$ gives a generating function for the Fuss-Catalan numbers (e.g., [OEIS A001764](https://oeis.org/A001764)).

Edit (April 2018):

More generally, let $h(h^{-1}(y))=y$ and $g(z) = 1/(dh(z)/dz)$. Then

$$ exp[t \cdot g(z) \frac{d}{dz}]f(z) = f[h^{-1}(t + h(z))] = f(W(t,z)), $$

which is analytic about $t=0$. Note that $W(t,W(s,z))=W(s+t,z)$ is the flow map described in OEIS [A145271](https://oeis.org/A145271) related to the refined Eulerian numbers and other number arrays related to important combinatorial structures--the associahedra and noncrossing partitions among others.

About $t=0$,

$$f[W(t,z)] = f(z) + f'(z)g(z)t + \cdots = (1 + t \cdot g(z) \frac{d}{dz}) f(z) + \cdots .$$

Since the composition and product of analytic functions are analytic, conformality is locally preserved.

Comment: See "Monstrous Moonshine and the classification of CFT" by Terry Gannon for an intuitive introduction to the Lie theory underlying the Witt algebra and central extension to a Virasoro algeba.

Comment: See also Cardy's discussion of the conformal anomaly in "The ubiquitous 'c': from the Stefan-Boltzmann law to quantum information" at http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2331.

Comment: The compositional inverse of $h(x)$ is also easily related to the combinatorics of non-crossing partitions and free probability in http://oeis.org/A134264.

Comment: On central extensions and quantum mechanics: Abstract Group Theory by Moore.

Comment: For relations to string theory and c to spacetime dimensions, see THE EARLY HISTORY OF STRING THEORY AND SUPERSYMMETRY
by John H. Schwarz  https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0981

Comment: Also "TASI Lectures on the Conformal Bootstrap" by
David Simmons-Duffin.

Comment: See the OEIS links for some relations of g(x) and h(x) to quantum field theory in the Balduf and the Kreimer and Yeats references.

Comment: For relations to the graded dual of the combinatorial Faa di Bruno Hopf algebras, related to functional composition, see "Faa di Bruno Hopf algebras" by Figueroa, Gracia-Bondi, and Varilly (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508337)

Comment: From The Geometry of Infinite-Dimensional Groups by Khesin and Wendt: Central extensions of Lie groups appear naturally in representation theory and quantum mechanics when one lifts a group projective representation to an ordinary one: one often needs to pass to a central extension of the group to be able to do this. For us the main advantage of these extensions is that for many infinite-dimensional groups their central extensions have simpler and “more regular” structure of the coadjoint orbits, as well as more interesting dynamical systems related to them.

Comment: See also p. 179 of "The Diffeomorphism Field" by Delalcan Kilic and p. 441 of "The merits and demerits of the orbit method" by Kirillov.

Comment: ~ p. 42 of "Boundary conformal field theories, limit sets of Kleinian groups and holography" by Arkady L. Kholodenko (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902167)

Comment: A little more on the history in the section "5.1 Vector fields, Witt and Virasoro Lie algebras" of "Five interpretations of Fa`a di Bruno’s formula" by Frabetti and  Manchon https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00950525

Comment: See Zamolodchikov, “‘Irreversibility’ of the
Flux of the Renormalization Group in a 2D
Field Theory” for a discussion of central charge in the renormalization group.

Comment: The inverse of $h(x) = x - t x^{m+1}$ for $m$ negative integers leads to interesting combinatorics as well. See, e.g., my MO-A to "A combinatorial interpretation for n-ary trees for negative n" (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441724/a-combinatorial-interpretation-for-n-ary-trees-for-negative-n).