# Cataland: Facets and partition polynomials of cluster complexes

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, gt.geometric-topology, polynomials, discrete-geometry

Figure 25 on pg. 101 of "[Cataland: Why the Fuss](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00710)?" by Christian Stump, Hugh Thomas, and Nathan Williams depicts cluster complexes (CCs) associated with generalized $(m)$-Narayana / noncrossing partitions / parking functions for $m$ a negative integer in my nomenclature and positive in theirs.

I have partition polynomials (ParPs) which give the number of facets of these CCs as the absolute value of the coefficients of the diagonals of the ParPs--see [this MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441724/a-combinatorial-interpretation-for-n-ary-trees-for-negative-n/441905#441905). However, from Fig. 25 it's evident that the facets can be separated into at least two distinct geometric shapes (if I interpret them correctly). Similar phenomena are associated with other closely related sets of ParPs as noted in the background section below.

**Does anyone have illustrations of the lower order cluster complexes that clearly depict the distinct families of facets as well as the lower dimensional faces?**

**Background**

Similar phenomena occur for the distinct types of facets--squares and pentagons--of the 3-dimensional associahedron, a convex polytope (see. e.g., [this MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145555/why-is-there-a-connection-between-enumerative-geometry-and-nonlinear-waves/181534#181534)), and the facets--squares and hexagons--of the 3-D permutahedron, another convex polytope. This bifurcation is reflected in the two distinct monomials of the ParPs associated with these facets, which are the ParPs for compositional inversion of o.g.f.s and multiplicative inversion of e.g.f.s, respectively. In fact (in response to Sam's comment), the ParPs associated with these two families of polytopes encode in their monomials ALL of the geometric / topological aspects of the faces (1-D vertices, 2-D edges, 3-D polygons, etc.); i.e., there is a clean bijection between the monomials and the distinct geometric constructs.

In a less clean fashion, this phenomenon extends partially to the more complicated simplicial complexes the tropical Grassmannians $G(2,n)$ associated with the mono-variate Ward polynomials ([A134991](https://oeis.org/A134991)), a natural reduction of the set $[L]$ of classic Lagrange Parps ([A134685](https://oeis.org/A134685)) for compositional inversion of e.g.f.s. For details, see "[Phylogenetic trees, augmented perfect matchings, and a Thron-type continued fraction (T-fraction) for the Ward polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.01468)" by Price and Sokal. In seeking a potential generalization to the ParpS, scanning "[The Tropical Grassmannian](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304218)" by Speyer and Sturmfels, you can see a correspondence between the coefficients of $L_3 = -15 u_1^3 + 10 u_1 u_2 -u_3$ and the vertices and edges of the simplicial complex $T_5$, the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph), and a correspondence between a breakdown of $T_6$ in Example 4.1 on pg. 8 of S & S and $L_4 = 105 u_1^4 - 105  u_1^2 u_2 + 15 u_1 u_3 + 10  u_2^2 -  u_4 $. A general bijection with the ParPs, however, is still an open problem, as Price and Sokal note.

This close linkage between the algebraic / analytic combinatorics of ParPs and the combinatorics of related geometric constructs, whether polytopes or more complicated complexes, suggest exploring parallels for the Cataland cluster complexes and associated ParPs. I'm not familiar with CCs, so to suggest and test conjectural modifications, I've posed the request for illustrations and certainly further references would also be appreciated.

The model presented in Cataland is different from other models associated with the $(m)$-Narayana ParPs. For $m>1$, analytic / algebraic / geometric combinatorics of the refined $(m)$-Narayana ParPs are inherited from those of the refined Narayana ParPs (see. e.g., [this MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338905/guises-of-the-noncrossing-partitions-ncps)). The same applies for $m < 1$ with respect to the inverse refined Narayana polynomials except this set doesn't have quite the variety of geometric models as the set of refined Narayana ParPS does (see [this MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412573/combinatorics-for-the-action-of-virasoro-kac-schwarz-operators-partition-poly)).

(I know two or three ways to analytically refine the Fuss-Narayana numbers, the coefficients of the diagonals of the $(m)$-Narayana ParPs, that enumerate the Cataland facets. Whether these can cleanly be or should be incorporated into the more encompassing algebraic combinatorics is another matter.)

Edit April 18, 2023:

Nathan Williams responded to an email I sent him with an alternate dual representation of his cluster complexes that seems to correlate with at least a variant of the reduced polynomials for the $(m)-$Narayana partition polynomials as face polynomials. I'll encourage him to present his observations as an answer here. This correlate also with Armstrong's thesis "Generalized Noncrossing Partitions and Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups".

Comment: You don't actually need geometric pictures to capture the difference between e.g. square faces and hexagonal faces. A square face contains 4 vertices (& 4 edges), while a hexagonal face has 6. So this kind of information is captured by the "abstract" combinatorial structure of the polytope, in the sense of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_polytope

Comment: @SamHopkins, I'm looking for the busy crossroads rather than quiet alleys, and yes it is much more difficult to associate the ParPs for the comp. inverse of e.g.f.s with Grassmannian simplicial complexes (not convex polytopes)--that hasn't stopped Thron, Price, Getzler, Cachazo from doing so or forming more complicated links between alg. and geom. comb. The associahedra and noncrossing ParPs (not polytopes) have been linked with more complex analytics and QFT. The m-associahedra and m-noncrossing partitions are related to Feynman diagrams as well. Algebra and geometry inform each other.

Comment: See also p. 121 of Nathan Williams' thesis "Cataland" (https://conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299/159973).

Comment: Perhaps these two papers more directly address my concerns:  "Rational associahedra and noncrossing partitions" by Armstrong, Rhoades, and Williams and "Rational parking functions and Catalan numbers" by Armstrong, Loehr, and Warrington.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445388/interpretations-of-the-m-fuss-narayana-numbers-for-m-0

Answer (score 1):

You can get [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) / [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/) to produce this information for you.

See the document at: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/cluster_complex.html.

For instance

```
C = ClusterComplex(['A', 3]) 
C
C.face_poset().show(figsize=15)
```

produces output:

[image]

Comment: Nice app, I rarely do coding anymore, so thanks. Nathan Williams sent me an email giving the face vectors  (7, 6, 1) and (30,36,12,1), which in my terminology correlates with $N^{(-2)}_3 =  7 u_1^3 - 6 u_2 u_1 + u_3$ and $N^{(-2)}_4 = -30 u_1^4 + 36 u_2 u_1^2 - 8 u_3 u_1 - 4 u_2^2 + u_4$. You'll find (7,6,1) in Armstrong on p. 144.

Comment: Got bored with writing up some details of some proofs, came back to this question as a respite, and noticed the nodes at the three levels sum, starting from the top, to 14, 21, and 9, which are the number of vertices, edges, and facets of the 3-D associahedra, respectively. The refined face numbers of the associahedra are intimately related to the noncrossing partitions, which, in turn, are intimately related to  refined (m)-Narayana / (m)-noncrossing partitions numbers for m a positive integer. My question addresses m for negative numbers (e.g., m=-2 in comment above).

Comment: See my answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441724/a-combinatorial-interpretation-for-n-ary-trees-for-negative-n/441905#441905 for some more notes on the differences for m positive and m negative.