# Connections to physics, geometry, geometric probability theory of Euler's beta integral (function)

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, gt.geometric-topology, cv.complex-variables, operator-theory

Euler"s integral for the beta function $B(s,\alpha) = $ (with $x = 1$)

$$ \frac{(s-1)!(\alpha-1)!}{(s+\alpha-1)!} x^{s+\alpha-1} = \int_0^\infty t^{s-1}\; H(x-t) \; (x-t)^{\alpha-1} dt = \int_0^x t^{s-1} \; (x-t)^{\alpha-1} \; dt $$

is one of those iconic equations at the intersection of several domains of physics and mathematical analysis that serve as leaping boards to far-reaching generalizations (see, e.g., [Beta integrals](http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/%7Euqowarna/talks/Wien.pdf) by Warnaar and [The importance of the Selberg integral](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3981) by Forrester and Warnaar).

What salient connections to physics, geometry, and geometric probability theory does the Euler beta integral have?

**Some associations**:

**I) Fractional / operational calculus**: It can be viewed as a Mellin transform or a Laplace transform convolution integral, or morph into the core Riemann-Liouville fractional integroderivative of fractional calculus analytically continued (e.g., by the Hadamard finite part regularization, cf. "[Fractional calculus and interpolation of generalized binomial coefficients](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2015/08/15/fractional-calculus-and-sinc-function-interpolation-of-generalized-binomial-coefficients/)")

$$ D_x^{-s} x^{\alpha}= \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; H(x-t) \; (x-t)^\alpha dt = \int_0^x \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; (x-t)^\alpha \; dt = \frac{\alpha!}{(\alpha+s)!} x^{s+\alpha} \; . $$

**II) String theory:** The connection between the Veneziano amplitude of nascent string theory and the beta function is well-known. For a very nice overview, see "[The Euler Legacy to Modern Physics](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1009/1009.5313.pdf)" by Dattoli.

**II) Schwarz triangle, Ehrhart polynimials, and polytopes**:  Kholodenko in [New strings for old Veneziano amplitudes: I Analytical treatment](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0410242v3.pdf) and [New models for Veneziano amplitudes: Combinatorial, symplectic, and supersymmetric aspects](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0503232)  reviews the string theory connections also and links to a geometric interpretation as lengths of sides of a Schwarz triangle and to Ehrhart polynomials encoding a relation between number of interior points of convex lattice polytopes and the number of their boundary points. See also the Physics Overflow question [Relation of Betti numbers to Veneziano's scattering amplitude?](http://physicsoverflow.org/24003/relation-of-betti-numbers-venezianos-scattering-amplitude).

The relation to the Schwarz triangle is nicely presented in [Gauss' hypergeometric function](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Ebeuke106/GaussHF.pdf) by Beukers.

**III Pochhammer contour integration over Riemann surfaces**: The integral formulated as a Pochhammer contour integral over Riemann surfaces is beautifully depicted in [Exploring visualization methods for complex variables](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2010/2699/pdf/8.pdf). [Edit 1/3/2021: See also a "[A Contour Integral Representation for the Dual Five-Point Function and a Symmetry of the Genus Four Surface in R6](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0510064)" by Hanson and Sha on relations among associahedra, string theory, cross-ratios, the Pochhammer contour, generalized beta integrals, and projective spaces.]

**IV: Diff op dualities, symmetric polynomials, and Appell sequences**:

There is a dual operator ($D^{s}x^s$, the inverse of $x^{-s}D^{-s}$) and Mellin transform that illuminates the connection to generalizations of symmetric polynomials (and, therefore, the exterior algebra and simplices) by the Weierstrass factorization theorem for meromorphic functions, in this case the generalized rising and falling factorials:

$$ (x D_x x)^{-s} \; x^\alpha = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; \frac{x^\alpha}{(1+xt)^{\alpha+1}} \; dt = x^{\alpha-s} \frac{(\alpha-s)!}{\alpha!} = x^{-s} D_x ^{-s} x^{-s} \; x^\alpha \; $$

$$= x^{-s} \frac{(xD_x-s)!}{(xD_x)!} \; x^\alpha \; .$$

These factorials specialize to the gamma function and its reciprocal with $\alpha = 0$ and further, with $x = e^z$, to the e.g.f.s for the gamma characteristic classes or genuses, $\frac{e^{sz}}{s!}$ and $e^{sz}s!$ with the periods $\zeta(n>1)$ as coefficients (power functions) for the dual raising operators of the associated dual Appell polynomials (i.e., the Appell polynomials of the two e.g.f.s form an inverse pair under umbral composition). (Cf. [Perturbative corrections to Kahler moduli spaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2157)  by Halverson, Jockers, Lapan, and Morrison for an application.) These sequences are naturally connected by the cycle index partition polynomials (CIPP, [OEIS-A036039](https://oeis.org/A036039)) for the symmetric group (Hall-Macdonald scheme and Newton identities). In fact, the operadic infinitesimal generators for the dual operators are these raising operators which are (with the coefficients treated as indeterminates) generators of the CIPP and its umbral compositional inverse.

There is also a connection to Koszul duality, reflecting that, for $z=0$, the e.g.f.s are a multiplicative inverse pair, and to the Kummer confluent hypergeometric functions (cf. this [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107159/pochhammer-symbol-of-a-differential-and-hypergeometric-polynomials/107191#107191)).

Comment: Any additional, good references on the associations already mentioned would be appreciated by me and I"m sure by others who might be interested in the topics.

Comment: This is a connection in a different direction, but the corresponding sum over a finite field is called a twisted Kloosterman sum.

Comment: @AllenKnutson, interesting. I wasn't aware of these finite analogs before: Hermite Character Sums by Evans http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102701891

Comment: I just added the Warnaar and Forrester papers that discuss the finite analogs that Allen noted, as well as other generalizations and history.

Comment: A related MO-Q: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153542/geometric-interpretation-of-the-half-derivative

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/beta-function-derivation/3540#3540

Comment: "Gravity and Strings" by Giddings https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0501080

Comment: See "Single-valued integration and superstring amplitudes in genus zero" by Francis Brown, Clément Dupont. https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07682

Comment: "Superstring Amplitudes, Unitarity, and Hankel Determinants of Multiple Zeta Values" by Michael B. Green, Congkao Wen     https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08426

Comment: ”New" Veneziano amplitudes from
”old” Fermat (hyper)surfaces:  by A.L.Kholodenko1(https://cds.cern.ch/record/597592/files/0212189.pdf)

Comment: "Combinatorics and Topology of Kawai-Lewellen-Tye Relations" by
Sebastian Mizera https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08527

Comment: "OVERVIEW: POSITIVE GEOMETRIES AND AMPLITUDES "  http://math.mit.edu/~tfylam/posgeom/intro.pdf

Comment: See panel 11 of "Positive Geometries: by Lam https://diehlj.github.io/amplituhedron/AmplituhedronDay21-Lam.pdf

Comment: "The Feynman iε in String Theory" by Witten https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.5124

Comment: "Celestial Operator Products of Gluons and Gravitons" byMonica Pate, Ana-Maria Raclariu, Andrew Strominger, and Ellis Ye Yuan https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.07424

Comment: See "Simplicity in AdS Perturbative Dynamics" by Yuan (https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07283).

Comment: The reciprocal, $\frac{(a+b-1)!}{a!b!}$, has interpretations in "Rational associahedra and noncrossing partitions" by Armstrong, Rhoades, and Williams and "Rational parking functions and Catalan numbers" by Armstrong, Loehr, and Warrington (p. 8).

Answer (score 2):

The Euler beta function governs the statistics of [Preferential attachment processes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferential_attachment)

> A preferential attachment process is any of a class of processes in
>   which some quantity, typically some form of wealth or credit, is
>   distributed among a number of individuals or objects according to how
>   much they already have, so that those who are already wealthy receive
>   more than those who are not. The distribution is given asymptotically by a ratio of Beta functions. Because the Beta function decays as a powerlaw, the preferential attachment process generates a "long-tailed" distribution. Preferential attachment is used to model the distribution of the sizes of cities, the wealth of the rich, the number of citations to scientific publications, and the number of links to web pages.

Comment: And so, according to the Wiki, related to probabilistic speciation equivalent to a type of tree growth (?).