# Has anyone seen these binary trees (Catalan-type related to the Gegenbauer polynomials and Motzkin paths)?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, polynomials, oeis

The OEIS entry [A121448](http://oeis.org/A121448) enumerates binary trees with $n$ edges and $k$ vertices with outdegree 1.

Has anyone seen these trees?

The o.g.f. for this entry, $G(x,t)$, is essentially a discriminant whose associated row polynomials can be generated as an umbral composition of the reverse face polynomials of the hypercubes [A038207](http://oeis.org/A038207) with the aerated Catalan numbers [A126120](http://oeis.org/A126120). The compositional inverse of $G$ is the o.g.f. of the [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the second kind [A053117](http://oeis.org/A053117) (mod signs). More generally, the row polynomials of G are invariant polynomials of the compositional inverses of the o.g.f.s (times a factor $x^{\alpha}$) of the [Gegenbauer polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials) of differing order $\alpha$. The row polynomials of $G$ are also related to the Motzkin paths of [A097610](http://oeis.org/A097610).

Given the rich associations among these combinatoric structures, polygon dissections, lattice paths, orthogonal polynomials, Cartan-Lie algebras, and compositional inverses and algebraic geometry/topology, I would hope these binary trees (or row polynomials) have explicitly popped up in other literature.

Comment: Added the statistic to FindStat at http://www.findstat.org/St000385. But no relations to other statistics came up :-(

Comment: @Christian, thanks. Of course, the non-aerated, reflected array  has shown up in several publications, but I'm hoping for a little more.